# python file does not run properly on Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I am using Spyder as my python IDE.

I tried run this python code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

path = os.getcwd() + '\ex1data1.txt'
data = pd.read_csv(path, header = None, names = ['Population', 'Profit'])
data.head()
```

In theory it is supposed to show me a table of data since I am using

```
data.head()
```

at the end

but when I run it, it only shows :

[image]

I thought it was supposed to display a new window with the data table.

What is wrong?

Comment: Nothing, look at your variable explorer pan, you will find data (type: dataframe) click that and you can see your data. To print data head in console you have to type `print(data.head())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `data.head()` in `.py` script. The script is supposed to only read the data, not print it. Try `print(data.head())`

Answer (score 1):

You want to print your data.head() so do that...
`print(data.head())`